# Show that if R is ring with identity, $xy$ and $yx$ have inverse and $xy=yx$ then y has an inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that if R is ring with identity, $xy$ and $yx$ have inverse and $xy=yx$ then  y has an inverse.

I said we have an $a=xy^{-1}=yx^{-1}$ 
I did some operations on $xy=yx$ but i couldnt prove

Comment: Consider $1=(yx)(xy)^{-1}=y(x(xy)^{-1})$

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What a weird way to say the question. Why say "$a$ and $b$ have inverses and oh yeah $a=b$".  In fact one doesn't need to say $xy=yx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$(yx)(yx)^{-1}=1$$
By associativity, this is
$$y(x(yx)^{-1})=1$$
so a right inverse of $y$ is $x(yx)^{-1}$.

You would also want to know that it has a left inverse. Thus we consider
$$(xy)^{-1}(xy)=1$$
so
$$((xy)^{-1}x)y=1$$
hence $(xy)^{-1}x$ is a left inverse of $y$. As I'm sure you know, if an element has both a left and a right inverse then they are equal, so $y$ has an inverse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sure, @BERAT. ${}$

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis there exists an $a$ and a $b$ such that $axy=yxb=1$.

Therefore $ax=xb=y^{-1}$.